# Android SQLite date('now') not accurate

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

If I run this query in my Android Emulator, it outputs `2014-05-11`:

```
SELECT date('now');
```

If I run this javascript (using date.js) in the same emulator, it outputs `2014-05-12`:

```
new Date().toString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

If I go to the emulator's *System setting > Date & Time*, it is `5/12/2014`, which means the javascript result is correct.

So how can I fix this? Does it has something to do with GMT setting? My current solution is to avoid all `date('now')` function calls in SQL (i have replaced them with):

```
var sql = " SELECT '"+new Date().toString(yyyy-MM-dd)+"' ";
```

Comment: What timezone is set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timezones. `SELECT date('now')` returns the current date in UTC. `new Date().toString("yyyy-MM-dd")` uses the local timezone. Your local timezone is 12-May while UTC is still 11-May.

To get local time in SQL, use `SELECT date('now', 'localtime')` instead.